# In Angular JS, How to pass value to provider?

Tags: angularjs

For some reasons, I want to pass  masterapp.value ('mastervalue' , 'XYZ') to provider. How to do that ? Below approach throw error.

```
var masterapp= angular.module('masterapp',[]);

masterapp.value ('mastervalue' , 'XYZ');

masterapp.provider('masterprovider', ['mastervalue', function(mastervalue) {

    this.myFn = function() {
        return mastervalue;
    };

 }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it constant if that is fine with you (cannot be changed). So the updated code will be:

```
var masterapp= angular.module('masterapp',[]);

masterapp.constant('mastervalue' , 'XYZ');

masterapp.provider('masterprovider', ['mastervalue', function(mastervalue) {

    this.myFn = function() {
        return mastervalue;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/constants-values-global-variables-in-angularjs-the-right-way/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if .value can be returned like that. Try assigning it first within scope and then using that value to create the function.

```
this.masterValue = mastervalue;
this.myFun = function(){
      return this.masterValue
}
```